# Remote Database access

Tags: android, database

I'm really a beginner, I'm reading many different Android books as I would like to learn how to develop my own app.

The app I've in mind is going to access to a remote database in order the write and read data. I would like to ask your advise about how this is usually done, best practices.

I want to learnt about databases as I actually know so little (just how to make some sql queries and procedures) and I would like to focus my learning towards Android integration.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a server-side-service that will allow you to manipulate your data from your Android device.

There is no easy way of connecting Android DIRECTLY to a remote database.

You solution should be something like this:

```
ANDROID -> SERVER-SIDE-SERVICE -> DATABASE
DATABASE -> SERVER-SIDE-SERVICE -> ANDROID
```

For your SERVER-SIDE-SERVICE I would recommend you use any WEB/HTTP server side service written in your favorite language: Java, Python, ASP.NET (C#/VB.NET), PHP, you name it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pablo. I really appreciate your answer, it seems very sensible to have a server-side-server.
 
Do you know where I kind find more detailed information?

Comment: Write a simple PHP script that you will access through HTTP CLIENT from Android. Is the way you will find more information about. Google for: "php mysql".

Comment: Lets hope I'have a web server (Apache or IIS) and the PHP interpreter which will comunicatewith my DB (mySQL) for example.
I should use the public interface
HttpClient of android to communicate with the web server (with the DB)? Correct?

Comment: OK, thank you very much, you've been very kind, now I just have to learn how the hell this HttpClient works. Thanks