# What is the best way to get data from an android app into a remote database?

Tags: javascript, android, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote Database access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897466/remote-database-access)

I'm developing an app for android which shoult connect itself to a remoe mysql-database.

So far I know what to do to get the app running visually...but how can I transfer the data into a remote database?

What kind of processes have to be developed to get the data into the right shape so that a websserver can translate that and put it into a database?

What do i have to do for getting:

1. the right structure of the data
2. transfer/translate/design an interface to bring data to a remote server (--> is it possible to use javascript only)?

What do i have to use? Ajax/JASON etc.

Anyone can help me out on this question of architecture?

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig the question is similar, but i meant it different...i know what to do on the serverside...but how the get data from the android device to a server, where a script can do something with the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create some RESTful web services to access the mysql database, then the Android app can call the web service to get or post data to the db, use XML or JSON as the format of data.

Comment: thanks for your answer...is there a good tutorial on "RESTful web services" you can recommend?

Comment: check out some stuff on developerWorks http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/ and one tutorial Building RESTful Web Services with Jersey http://matthewturland.com/slides/jersey/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your remote database. If it is [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/) for example, you just do simple HTTP requests.

If it is SQL you can use JDBC like other client applications would, too.

But perhaps you don't want to have database passwords on your clients. Then you will have to create a web application which is connected to your database. This web application then could provide your favorite (JSON over HTTP) protocol to your android clients.

Comment: @ Witek i made some changes in my question...thanks...i like to put that data into a mysql database...

Comment: @ witek is it also possible to have it the other way round...like the client device sends a JSON/HTTP protocol to a web application?

Comment: Your web app is a HTTP server which receives HTTP requests. Based on request parameters it makes queries to the local database. As a response it sends HTTP responses containing JSON data to your Android application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at web APIs. Most common is [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language)/[SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP). In regards to the structure, I'd advise you to take a look at JSON. XML works as well, but is pretty redundant. There is also the possibility of using [Remote Method Invocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation) with Java, but that's usually not really worth the effort, I think.